# JOIN where row may not exist in one table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
students
+-------+------+
| id    | name |
+-------+------+
| 1     | Bob  |
+-------+------+
| 2     | Sam  |
+-------+------+
```

and

```
courses
+----+------------+---------+--------+
| id | student_id | teacher | period |
+----+------------+---------+--------+
| 1  |    1       | Mr. X   |    1   | 
+----+------------+---------+--------+
| 2  |    1       | Ms. Y   |    2   |
+----+------------+---------+--------+
| 3  |    2       | Mr. X   |    2   | 
+----+------------+---------+--------+
| 4  |    2       | Ms. Y   |    3   |
+----+------------+---------+--------+
```

And this is the result I need from these two tables:

```
list of students and period 1 teacher
+------------+------+-----------------+
| student_id | name | period 1 teacher|
+------------+------+-----------------+
| 1          |  Bob |       Mr. X     | 
+------------+------+-----------------+
| 2          |  Sam |       null      | 
+------------+------+-----------------+
```

Okay, I need a list of students and the teacher they have for a certain period (in this case, period 1).  They may, however, have no teacher listed for that period in the courses table, in which case I want 'null' for that column on that student (as above with 'Sam').

The closest I have is this:

```
SELECT students.id,students.name,courses.teacher
FROM students
LEFT JOIN courses ON students.id = courses.student_id AND courses.period = '1'
```

But I only ever get back rows that exist in BOTH tables (in this example, only the 'Bob' student would be returned since 'Sam' has no period 1 teacher.

I feel certain it is something simple, but my Google-fu has failed me thus far.

Comment: Your query works for me. Did you run the query above on data above? Maybe you JOIN on different column (i.e. `courses.id`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT students.id,students.name,courses.teacher
FROM students
LEFT JOIN (select * from courses WHERE courses.period = '1') courses
ON students.id = courses.student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly and according to the context is to appear only the student BOB.

Assuming it to be true, replace the LEFT for INNER what will work.

```
SELECT students.id,students.name,courses.teacher
FROM students
INNER JOIN courses ON students.id = courses.student_id AND courses.period = '1'
```

I hope it is useful